# How on MW2 do You Play With Friends on Free-for-all

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

My friend and I were trying to play an online free for all match on Modern Warfare 2, but it said only one person per party. Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invite your friend.

You need to be in a match, and there has to be at most (maxPlayers_allowed - 2) people on the host.

Comment: So, I can invite my friend when I am already in the match?

Comment: It's best to do this in the lobby, since most lobbies fill up very quickly. But you can do it also during the game.